# I can't resolve this error : Check the render method of `App`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have installed react-router-dom to my project and adjusted my index.js file to support it but for some reason, it breaks my app. Here's the complete error message:

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.**

This is how it's highlighted in the error report:

```
  5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
   7 | 
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(
   9 |   <Router>
  10 |     <App />
  11 |   </Router>,
```

here's my App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from "react-router";
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import HeaderMenu from './components/HeaderMenu'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage'
import Works from './components/Works'
import Info from './components/Info'
import Contact from './components/Contact'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userView: 0
  }

  handleChange = (userView) => {
    userView === 0 ? this.setState({ userView: 1}) : this.setState({ userView: 0})
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderMenu
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        userView={this.state.userView}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => (
          <MainPage />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/works"
        render={() => (
          <Works />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/info"
        render={() => (
          <Info />
        )}
      />
      <Route
      exact
      path="/contact"
      render={() => (
        <Contact/>
      )}
    />
    </div>
  );
  }
 }

 App.propTypes = {
  userView: PropTypes.oneOf([0, 1]).isRequired
}
```

here's my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You have to change your import from `import { Route } from "react-router";` to `import { Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Do these required changes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import HeaderMenu from './components/HeaderMenu'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage'
import Works from './components/Works'
import Info from './components/Info' 
import Contact from './components/Contact'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userView: 0
}

handleChange = (userView) => {
    userView === 0 ? this.setState({ userView: 1}) : this.setState({ userView: 0})
}

render() {
return (
   <div className="App">
      <HeaderMenu
         handleChange={this.handleChange}
         userView={this.state.userView}
      />
      <Switch>
         <Route
           exact
           path="/"
           render={() => (
             <MainPage />
           )}
         />
        <Route
           exact
           path="/works"
           render={() => (
             <Works />
           )}
        />
        <Route
           exact
           path="/info"
           render={() => (
             <Info />
           )}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/contact"
          render={() => (
            <Contact/>
          )}
        />
     </Switch>
   </div>
  );
}}

App.propTypes = {
  userView: PropTypes.oneOf([0, 1]).isRequired
}

export default App;
```

add the **export default App;** in the bottom and also wrap to the **Route** using **Switch**

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, Share your project's CodePen link. [GitHub won't work]

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with code pen can you clone the repository from github?

Comment: Okay, share your GitHub repo. of your project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the suggestions so far. I tried to recreate the problem with a new react project and it didn't happen so I think I might have done something wrong earlier (this was a full-stack rails/ react project). Anyway, I've started over and the problem is gone.